# Magento Indexing 1.9

Tags: magento

Been having some problems reindexing in a new install of Magento 1.9.1.0. I have been re-indexing from admin and from shell. Both seem to reindex successfully but the admin screen immediatley returns to 'reindex required'. I have checked to see if var/locks exists, and it doesn't.

Our data was migrated from a Magento 1.8. All the attributes migrated with the prefix 'c2c_' which meant that some of the attribute names were too long. We manually edited these in the database to remove the 'c2c_'  Could this be the problem?

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: If you have original database of your Magento 1.8 then try to use that and see.

Comment: I have a dev copy of the 1.9 site where I tired to replicate the problem by renaming the same attributes but that indexes without any problems so I guess that is not the issue.